# Siege does not send POST data

Tags: post, load-testing

I'm trying to test my site with siege 3.0.1. But it seems that siege does not send POST data. Here is a request I get from web-browser

```
POST / HTTP/1.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 130
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: rsc
Origin: http://rsc
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: http://rsc/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.52 Safari/537.36
X-Forwarded-For: 127.0.0.1
X-Forwarded-Proto: http
X-Real-Ip: 127.0.0.1

came_from=http%3A%2F%2Frsc%2F&login=***&password=***&form.login=%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C
```

And here a request from siege

```
siege -g "http://rsc/ POST came_from=http%3A%2F%2Frsc%2F&login=***&password=***&form.login=%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C"

POST / HTTP/1.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: 
Content-Length: 111
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: rsc
User-Agent: JoeDog/1.00 [en] (X11; I; Siege 3.0.1)
X-Forwarded-For: 127.0.0.1
X-Forwarded-Proto: http
X-Real-Ip: 127.0.0.1
```

Am I doing something wrong? I checked siege documentation and it says nothing about POST except I should write `POST my=params` after url.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [Siege home page](http://www.joedog.org/siege-home/), 3.0.1 has a major bug with HTTP POST and the author suggests upgrading to 3.0.2

Comment: Currently `apt-get install siege` will install siege 3.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem - siege would not post, however the result was a "200" and then a "General Error". I tried everything, the end result: I rolled back to a previous version of 2.7.2 from 3.0.1 and it mysteriously works. Fyi.

Comment: How did you revert to older version of siege?